# access UISwitch setting from a different view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, boolean, uiswitch

k, I'm new to this so apologies all around, generally.

I'm trying to access the UISwitch value (on or off) from a different view and class and can't make it work.

It's a simple 2 view app. Main view and the second is a preference menu.

trying to write an if/else method to play sound when the switch (on the other view) is on and not when its off.

I cant seem to make it work. Any thoughts or some syntax examples would really help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Some code demonstrating your current attempt could help a lot. Generally speaking, it's not good form to access UI components of one view controller from another...

Answer (score 4):

As Matt Wilding said "it's not good form to access UI components of one view controller from another...".

Instead of accessing the view object, when the switch state is changed by the user you save the status into NSUserDefaults as preference value. Whenever you want, you can access the switch status value through the preferences.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate it. I have to save those things anyway so this simplifies things.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take what I think you're trying to accomplish here and suggest an alternative approach.  You want to have a preference in your app (assumed from "preferences menu") that allows the user to set something like whether or not you app plays background music. (May not be exact, this is just for clarification).

Typically, in a well designed app, the flow is driven by the data, with the UI reflecting the state of the data model and the controllers coordinating the two layers.  What you are suggesting is to have your application play music based on the state of the UI, which is not backed by any data model. This cuts out the model level, and as you noticed, can lead to awkward attempts at communicating between the UI of different controllers for information.

Things like application preferences are typically stored in a nifty .plist file that is managed through the NSUserDefaults class. This would be a great place for the data level tracking of your preference.  In this situation, the UISwitch would represent the state of the flag in the settings file, and changing the value of the switch would change the value in the file.  Anywhere else in your application that you need to know if the play-sound-flag is set, you reference the data model info instead of the UI.  This decouples the view controllers from each other, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose add selector for swith and make NSInteger property in app delegate.Like the followed

[

```
yourSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

-(IBAction) switched: (id)sender
{
    int state=0;
    if(yourSwitch.on)
        state=1;
    else
             state=0;

 objAppDelegate.switchState=state;
}
```

then you need to access this appDelegate property in second view where you are playing sound
then according to this value you can do what you want and for making object of appDelegate class you need this line

```
YourAppDelegateClass *objAppDelegate=(YourAppDelegateClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

ok if you have any other doubt then you can ask.